# Строковые методы Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

*Добрый день! Как вы уже поняли, проблема с манипуляцией вывода текста. Выполняю тестовое задание на Python 2.7.*

```
quote = "Думаю, на мировом рынке можно будет продать штук пять компьютеров."
print("Исходная цитата: ")
print(quote)
print("\nОна же в верхнем регистре: ")
print(quote.upper())
print("\nВ нижнем регистре: ")
print(quote.lower())
print("\nКак заголовок: ")
print(quote.title())
print("\nС маленькой заменой: ")
print(quote.replace("штук пять", "Несколько миллионов"))
print("\nСнова исходная цитата: ")
print(quote)
raw_input("\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти из программы.")
```

При запуске вывод текста на каждый вариант - одинаковый. В чем проблема? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How to convert string to lowercase in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6797984/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас строки не Unicode. Если хотите использовать Python 2.7, то можете добавить перед кавычками "u", или то, как писали выше использовать unicode_literals.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

quote = u"Думаю, на мировом рынке можно будет продать штук пять компьютеров."
print(u"Исходная цитата: ")
print(quote)
print(u"\nОна же в верхнем регистре: ")
print(quote.upper())
print(u"\nВ нижнем регистре: ")
print(quote.lower())
print(u"\nКак заголовок: ")
print(quote.title())
print(u"\nС маленькой заменой: ")
print(quote.replace(u"штук пять", u"Несколько миллионов"))
print(u"\nСнова исходная цитата: ")
print(quote)
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, скинул код без шапки. Всегда добавляю кодировку. Вопрос закрыт. Еще раз всем спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Проблема, что вы Питон 3 код пытаетесь на python2 интепретаторе выполнять.

Чтобы исправить, нужно превратить константы в Unicode и объявить кодировку исходного кода:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# здесь ваш код без изменений
```

Иначе, вы вызываете `.lower()`, `.upper()`, etc для байтов, что может возвращать неверные результаты, как вы убедились. Для работы с текстом используйте Unicode:

```
>>> print b'я'.upper()  #XXX DO NOT DO IT
я
>>> print u'я'.upper() 
Я
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!